# Replacing Click-Once with another installer that supports non Windows Security

Tags: c#, wix, installation, clickonce

I currently have an in house C# app that is delivered via click-once. I'm moving to the cloud and would like to have the Click-Once delivered from there (will be accessed from multiple countries and I can't use IP ranges to block out intruders), but it appears that the only way to secure the download is using windows security which is not an option for my clients.

I'm looking for a nice way to deliver the initial software and then keep the clients updated.

I've heard about WIX but I can't seem to find any information around updates from the internet and it.

Does WIX support this? If so can someone point me at an example or reference?
If it doesn't support it is there another solution someone can recommend?

**Here is my usage scenario:**
- User logs into a website supplying credentials, (username/password or certificate) then has the ability to download and install the application.

- The application must check on startup of the app for a new version and if there is automatically download, install then run it. (would be nice if the user must resupply credentials for the update but not a necessity)

Bonus points if it will work on any web server such as a simple Node.js implementation.

Comment: In the end I had to create my own installer as the package needed to be delivered to anywhere in the world from AWS and Click-Once just wouldn't do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WiX Only handles the *installation via the bootstrapper or MSI you have generated*, so I would assume that it's most likely a windows installer setting of some kind when it is first created. The element `ClickThrough` is supposed to be able to handle this scenario, though I don't know much about that.

The way my work colleagues dealt with this is by using IIS and an ASP.NET web service, along with a DLL that has methods to check with the web service if there is an update, and then prompts the user about the update and asks if they wish to update (did I say update enough in that sentence?).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Too bad click-once didn't support more choices for authentication. In the end I wrote my own installer/bootstrapper to solve the issue.

Comment: The problem with ClickOnce is that its great for deployment, but can lead to security issues (hence it cannot be used for applications that must run as administrator), if we could change the authentication it would be even harder for Microsoft to manage ClickOnce as a whole in my opinion.